# elements in list according to truth value of three way condition

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

If I have a list L

```
L = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

and I have a list of truth values T

```
T = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
```

I can access the elements in L that correspond to values in T.

For example

```
L[T == 1] = [0,2,4,6,8]
L[T == 0] = [1,3,5,7,9]
```

My problem is this:
I have two truth lists T1 and T2, say:

```
T1 = [0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0]
T2 = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
```

I want the the elements in L that would be accessed by

```
L[T1 == T2 == 1] = [2,8]
```

or put another way

```
L[T1 == 1 and T2 == 1] = [2,8]
```

This triple condition doesn't seem to work for accessing elements in a list. How can I achieve the same result?

Comment: In python, `L[T == 1]` is `L[False]` because `T` is different from `1`. So you actually assign the list `[0,2,4,6,8]` to `L[False]` when you write `L[T == 1] = [0,2,4,6,8]`. What happens is `L[0]` is actually assigned. See, `L` contains then `[[0, 2, 4, 6, 8], 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. I think this is not what you want.

Comment: That's not standard python.  What library are you using on top of python?  You can use a list comprehension: `[x for l, t1, t2 in zip(L, T1, T2) if t1 and t2]`

Comment: @zezollo I don't think he meant that as an assignment, he's saying that the result of `L[T == 1]` equals `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]`. Is this Pandas notation?

Comment: It's in the context of plotting. The data i'm working with is 2d and it's a scatter plot
`from matplotlib import pylab as plb`
`plb.plot( L[T == 1 , 0] , L[T == 1 , 1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where [**`numpy`**](http://www.numpy.org/) shines:

```
import numpy as np

L = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
T1 = [0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0]
T2 = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]

mask = np.logical_and(T1, T2)

print(L[mask].tolist())
# [2, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out in the comment, what you're doing doesn't make any sense from a Python perspective. However, using one list as a mask on another list is fairly common and easy enough to do.

You can simply do

```
masked = [x for x, t1, t2 in zip(L, T1, T2) if t1 and t2]
```

Comment: Thank you! I realise how poorly phrased the question was. I've tried to clarify in my reply to the comments above. Im using pylab and numpy.